# Form Validation with JavaScript, only one of the inputs works

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to implement a custom validation for the form, however only one of my inputs actually work. What's more, the function, for some reason, doesn't recognize if there is any text or not in the input field.
Here is the code of one of the inputs of the form:

```
<form class="formWrapper">
          <div class="inputWrapper">
            <input
              class="formInput"
              required
              type="text"
              name="first-name"
              id="first-name"
              placeholder="First Name"
            />
            <img class="errorImg hidden" src="/images/icon-error.svg" />
            <div class="errorMessage hidden">
              <i>First name cannot be empty</i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="inputWrapper">
            <input
              class="formInput"
              required
              type="text"
              name="last-name"
              id="last-name"
              placeholder="Last Name"
            />
            <img class="errorImg hidden" src="/images/icon-error.svg" />
            <div class="errorMessage hidden">
              <i>Last Name cannot be empty</i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="inputWrapper">
            <input
              class="formInput"
              required
              type="text"
              name="Email"
              id="Email"
              placeholder="Email Address"
            />
            <img class="errorImg hidden" src="/images/icon-error.svg" />
            <div id="emailError" class="errorMessage hidden">
              <i>Email cannot be empty</i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="inputWrapper">
            <input
              class="formInput"
              required
              type="text"
              name="Password"
              id="Password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />
            <img class="errorImg hidden" src="/images/icon-error.svg" />
            <div class="errorMessage hidden">
              <i>Password cannot be empty</i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="claimButton">
            Claim Your Free Trial
          </button>
          <div class="termsSection">
            By clicking the button, you are agreeing to our
            <b class="redBold">Terms and Services</b>.
          </div>
        </form>
```

And here is the JavaScript code, that I have written.

```
"use strict";

const formInput = document.querySelectorAll(`.formInput`);
const errorImg = document.querySelector(`.errorImg`);
const errorMessage = document.querySelector(`.errorMessage`);
const submitButton = document.querySelector(`.claimButton`);
const firstName = document.querySelector(`#first-name`);
const lastName = document.querySelector(`#last-name`);
const email = document.querySelector(`#Email`);
const password = document.querySelector(`#Password`);

const inputFields = [
  { inputName: firstName },
  {
    inputName: lastName,
  },
  {
    inputName: email,
  },
  {
    inputName: password,
  },
];

const errorOccured = function (i) {
  errorMessage.classList.remove(`hidden`);
  errorImg.classList.remove(`hidden`);
  formInput.classList.add(`errorState`);
};

for (let i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
  inputFields[i].inputName.addEventListener("invalid", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}

submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
    if (inputFields[i].inputName.value === "") {
      errorOccured(i);
    }
  }
});
```

The form itself looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Please include the code for the form and both the inputs in question so that we can replicate your issue.

Comment: Also, you are using template literal syntax ` in your code, where you should just be using quotes.

Comment: I have added the code of the whole form in the question. @ScottMarcus

Comment: Why don't you disable submit button until all input fields are correctly filled?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner That was the point of the project, to have this form validation, without any restrictions on submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing both `querySelectorAll` and `querySelector` methods.

The `querySelectorAll` method returns a NodeList with all matched elements, one way to iterate through the result is using `for (let item of result) { }`, another way is using `result.forEach(function (item) { })`.

The `querySelector` method returns the first element matching the given selector/class. Then you can access `result.classList` on it, for example.

That said, I've made some changes to the submit handler, so it will validate the input fields by adding or removing the hidden class.

```js
const wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.inputWrapper');

for (let wrapper of wrappers) {
  const formInput = wrapper.querySelector('.formInput');
  formInput.addEventListener('invalid', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}

const submitButton = document.querySelector(`.claimButton`);
submitButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  for (let wrapper of wrappers) {
    const formInput = wrapper.querySelector('.formInput');
    const errorImg = wrapper.querySelector('.errorImg');
    const errorMessage = wrapper.querySelector('.errorMessage');

    if (!formInput.value) {
      errorImg.classList.remove('hidden');
      errorMessage.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      errorImg.classList.add('hidden');
      errorMessage.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.inputWrapper {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputWrapper">
  <input class="formInput" required type="text" name="first-name" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" />
  <img class="errorImg hidden" src="/images/icon-error.svg" />
  <div class="errorMessage hidden">
    <i>First name cannot be empty</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="inputWrapper">
  <input class="formInput" required type="text" name="last-name" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" />
  <img class="errorImg hidden" src="/images/icon-error.svg" />
  <div class="errorMessage hidden">
    <i>Last name cannot be empty</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="inputWrapper">
  <input class="formInput" required type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
  <img class="errorImg hidden" src="/images/icon-error.svg" />
  <div class="errorMessage hidden">
    <i>Email cannot be empty</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="inputWrapper">
  <input class="formInput" required type="text" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
  <img class="errorImg hidden" src="/images/icon-error.svg" />
  <div class="errorMessage hidden">
    <i>Password cannot be empty</i>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="claimButton">CLAIM YOUR FREE TRIAL</button>
```

Comment: *you must use for (let item of result) to iterate through the result.* <-- Or you can just call `.forEach()` on the result and loop directly.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Interesting, thought it was some feature included by core-js. It seems to be native now, I will edit it.

Comment: It's been native for quite some time.

Comment: Yep, accordingly to the MDN docs, only IE does not have support for [`Nodelist.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) now